# IN my code for some reason I get the "missing return statement" error

Tags: java

```
static String getString()
{
    String eisodos;
    InputStreamReader eisodosString = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(eisodosString);
    try
    {
        eisodos=br.readLine();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return "x";
    }
}
```

And what I get is that test.java:54: error missing return statement
                                              }

Comment: Please format your code properly by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K. Only use backticks for inline code. Also, the error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. You don't return anything despite declaring a function that returns `String`. You only return in the `catch` block, so if there's no exception it won't return anything.

Comment: you can't return inside `catch` block

Comment: @user3624028 Nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

Your method only returns something when an exception is thrown in your try block and caught in your catch block. It doesn't return anything otherwise. It must return a `String` in all possible scenarios.

Perhaps you should change

```
eisodos=br.readLine();
```

to

```
return br.readLine();
```

(if that's what you wish your method to return)

Answer (score 0):

Add return at your method like `return` `eisodos`:
Maybe your code becomes like this:

```
  static String getString()
    {                   
        String eisodos ;
        InputStreamReader eisodosString = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(eisodosString);
        try
            {
                eisodos=br.readLine();
            }
        catch(Exception e)
            {
                return "x";
            }
return eisodos;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it as it is at another computer and it did not shaw me that is misses an "}", I just now copy and pasted to another file alone (with the other parts of the code) and it was compiled) I think for some reason the compiler does does not recognise the { } ( ) ; sometimes